# How to share favorites among different browsers?

Tags: browser, bookmarks

I often use different browsers (IE7.0/8.0, Firefox 3.5, and Chrome) at work and home.
My favorite browser is Firefox, but I am still forced to use the other two because some intranet sites don't operate well with Firefox, and better with IE. Chrome is best when I work my stuffs on Google Apps or other highly javascript-densed jobs. While I'm working I always find some websites that I would like to bookmark, but I can never find a good way to synchronize my bookmarked websites across all the browsers.

Is there a tool or software (or any simple technique) to synchronize and manage all my favorite/bookmarked websites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried Social Bookmarking sites like [Delicious.com](http://delicious.com/)?  These provide way to Import and Export the Bookmarks.

Comment: I would like it if it's something not related to social media. I have to bookmark some intranet stuffs as well. I would also like to manage all of them together by folders/categories

Comment: Delicious is great. If there is no plugin for your browser, you may be able to use a bookmarklet, and in any case, your list is available at a URL. You can place bookmarks in under many tags simultaneously (or you can use one tag per site and treat your tags like folders), by typing your own or choosing ones that others have used. For intranet stuff you can check a box not to share the URL with others.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a website-based bookmark service like del.icio.us, you can try out [XMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) (formerly Foxmarks).

The Firefox add-on is the most robust, but there are also add-ons for Safari and Internet Explorer, and I'm expecting a Chrome version to be announced soon.  The single service synchronizes all your bookmarks between browsers on the same system and between systems.

The Firefox add-on supports sharing passwords as well, but the Safari/IE versions don't support this feature yet.

Comment: Xmarks is the only thing keeping me from Chrome and will mostly dump firefox one they make a Chrome version

Comment: Xmarks is great! I use it on my desktop and laptop, and it doesn't matter which browser I use (safari, Firefox, IE) - brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

[**Del.icio.us**](http://delicious.com/)...

- Lifehacker: [**Top 10 Ways to Use del.icio.us**](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/top-10-ways-to-use-delicious.html)
- **`tags`** and **`bundles`** does it -- wonder when **gmail** will get **`bundles`**
- **Export** for backup is a great idea

  - backup feels safe -- in case the site went down for extended periods
  - also lets you use the backed up data for other sorting

    - I have a script to convert the backup into a TiddlyWiki -- works great
- you could also [use the on-line api](http://www.grok.in/hacks/delicious-tag-management/)
- I have stopped using e-mail to **share links** (almost)

  - **`network`** and **`inbox`** help a lot
- Browser favorites are only used as launch-buttons now
- A powerful GTD Tool in general

One thing you will have when you try to use your bookmarks is the Internet.
So, that is the best place to keep them too.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Delicious](http://delicious.com/)** The tastiest bookmarks on the web.
>   Save your own or see what's fresh now!

.

> **[Yahoo booksmarks](http://bookmarks.yahoo.com/)** if you have a yahoo account.

**Organize.**
Categorize your bookmarks into folders with the touch of a button

**Explore.**
Find recommended sites similar to the sites you've bookmarked

**Access Anywhere.**
Easy access to your bookmarks from any computer, work or home

> **[Simpy](http://www.simpy.com/)** Simpy is a social bookmarking service that lets you save, tag, search and share your bookmarks, notes, groups and more

Answer (score 0):

Would a web service like del.icio.us or Simpy work for you as answer
to your question? You upload your bookmarks and then you can come back
to them later on the Internet.

http://del.icio.us/

http://www.simpy.com/

Another solution would be for you to save your bookmarks as an html
file. If you want instructions on how to do that, I could provide them
for you.

(or )

Syncing bookmarks among browsers

(or)

Transmute is a freeware bookmark conversion utility. TransmuteThis amazing, cross-platform utility will help you to try out different web browsers, synchronize bookmarks between systems, organize bookmarks, convert bookmarks for use in bookmark managers, share bookmarks with others and more. And best of all, it's free!! It works on Windows, linux as well as Mac OS X. Transmute is the first and only bookmark converter to export bookmarks, or favorites, between all of the major web browsers, which include :

```
* Google Chrome
* Mozilla Firefox
* Microsoft Internet Explorer
* OperaOpera
* Apple Safari
* Chromium
* Flock
* Konqueror
```

For Windows : http://www.gettransmute.com/download/Transmute110Setup.zip

For Linux and Mac: http://www.gettransmute.com/download/transmute-portable-1.10.tar.gz

Comment: Is Transmute a converter or a sync program?

Answer (score -1):

I use the [delicious](http://delicious.com/) suite, so all of my bookmarks are stored on the web and there are several sets of tools you can use to bookmark on delicious, and then view on whichever browser you happen to be on.

[Firefox](http://delicious.com/help/quicktour/firefox)
[IE](http://delicious.com/help/quicktour/ie)
For Chrome (or any other browser), you can use the delicious [bookmarklets](http://delicious.com/help/bookmarklets).